# Who manufacturers BLE devices with low distance or low tx power available or configurable

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

What BLE beacon models can be configuraged to only be detectable at around 5-7 meters?

I've only used one bluetooth manufacturer and getting the distance (using the signal strength (RSSI)) the distance was not consistently accurate enough.  It seems the most accurate way to get distances is by setting the power level lower and only check whether you are in range or not.

I don't know how the power levels translate to distances, so just looking at the txPower on manufacturer sites does not help much.  Preferably ones that are configurable and can also be configured to higher or even lower power levels.

Answer (score 0):

You could play with power level (Kontakt IO beacons supports it) but what you want to achieve is really difficult.

To be short, [here](https://blog.shinetech.com/2014/02/17/the-beacon-experiments-low-energy-bluetooth-devices-in-action/) is great, detailed, explanation of everything what I would wrote.

Hope it helps...